# Unity Android Facebook get profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a user profile picture with the new sdk (7.1.0) in unity but I can't figure it out. With the old fbresult we could just use the texture it gives but with the IGraphResult how do we get the texture?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this url for getting profile picture.

```
URL MyProfilePicURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=normal&method=GET&access_token="+ Access_token );
```

Comment: Thank's, it's working. Just changed URL by WWW and "me" by the id and it's all I wanted